# PGSQL Insert into A get ID to Insert into B

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert, sequence

Table A is a kind of unique sequence for all my tables.

```
-- Table: public."IdCentral"

-- DROP TABLE public."IdCentral";

CREATE TABLE public."IdCentral"
(
    "Id" bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"IdCentral_Id_seq"'::regclass),
    "Tag" character varying(127) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT "IdCentral_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Table B is any table of my database

```
-- Table: public."Users"

-- DROP TABLE public."Users";

CREATE TABLE public."Users"
(
    "Id" bigint NOT NULL,
    "Login" character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
    CONSTRAINT "PK" FOREIGN KEY ("Id")
        REFERENCES public."IdCentral" ("Id") MATCH FULL
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public."Users"
    OWNER to dba;
```

When I want to insert into B, I need to create a new record in A passing the B Table name as Tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [CURRVAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html):

```
SELECT CURRVAL('IdCentral_Id_seq');
```

... which will give you the current value for the ID sequence after insert.  For safety, it's best to use it inside a transaction, especially if you're combining it with load-balancing:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO "a" ...
INSERT INTO "b" VALUES ( CURRVAL('IdCentral_Id_seq', ... )
COMMIT;
```

That being said, it appears that you're implementing a "universal ID" system for your database.  This is something every new DBA tries (I did), and it's inevitably a bad idea which you end up spending a lot of time refactoring out later.  If there's some reason you genuinely need some kind of universal ID, consider using a UUID instead.